# How to change box color in transition plot (Gmisc package)

Tags: r, plot, transition, gmisc

I want to make transition plot with three columns. I use Gmisc package but not the transitionPlot function since it does not enable me include third column. Therefore, I used the code below. My problem is that my result transition table is dark green and there is box shadow. Could you please help me how I can change the color and get rid of the shadow? Thank you. This is my first inquiry, if there is something wrong, sorry.

Here a dataframe sample (I took this from stackoverflow, since I do not have the data):

```
x <- structure(list(Obs = 1:13, Seq.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c" ), class = "factor"), Seq.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("c", "d"), class = "factor"), Seq.3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "d", "e"), class = "factor"),     Seq.4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "f"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Obs", "Seq.1", "Seq.2", "Seq.3", "Seq.4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))


library(Gmisc)
library(dplyr)
transitions <- table(x$Seq.1,x$Seq.2) %>%
getRefClass("Transition")$new(label=c("1st Iteration", "2nd Iteration"))
transitions$box_width = 0.25;
transitions$box_label_cex = 0.7;
transitions$arrow_type = "simple";
transitions$arrow_rez = 300;
table(x$Seq.2,x$Seq.3) %>% transitions$addTransitions(label = '3rd Iteration')
transitions$render()
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example

Comment: Thank you, I edited my inquiry.

Comment: great. Good luck with your question :)

Comment: BTW, you can add Gmisc tag, it will highlight your question for people, who follow this package